# redux react update array after copying array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a question I'm facing a problem that I can't update array after copying it.
If I copy an array and don't update the id, when I type something on input the text will appear in the same way where I copy it.

here is my Initialstate

```
const initialState = [
  {
    id: random numbers,
    options: [{ id: random numbers , value: '' },
    ],
  },
];
```

it will have a lot of option
and I just would like to update options id

this is what i tried

```
    case COPY_QUESTION: {
      const newArray = [...state];
      const copyQuestion = newArray[action.payload];
        copyQuestion.options.map((option) =>
          Object.assign({}, option, {
            id: random number,
          }),
        );
      
      return [...state, copyQuestion];
    }
```

thanks for reading my question.

Comment: In your case, `newArray[action.payload]` is basically the same as `state[action.payload]`. Because with `const newArray = [...state];` you are not copying the objects, but the reference of the objects to a new array. What you need is a deep copy here. Or you have to copy all the values down the line as well.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. after that How do i update options id? I need to update it for drag and drop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's caused due to call-by-reference.
As I can see in your code,
You are copying the reference of an array which might have the reason to overwrite details of the original array when you are typing. You can copy the values of the original array by using Javascript Object Prototype

so in that, you need to destruct your array or break your reference in the duplicate array.
**example**

```
let A = [a,b,c]  //original Array
let B =  JSON.parse(JSON.strigify(A))  // duplicate Array
```